# RIKEN integrated database of mammals

Tags: biology, japan

The RIKEN integrated database of mammals is an integrated database of multiple large-scale programs that have been promoted by the RIKEN institute. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIKEN_integrated_database_of_mammals))

Where can this database be downloaded?

What is its license?

Comment: Have you come across http://metadb.riken.jp/ ? It seems as thought it might be a compilation of many databases..

Answer (score 2):

Here is the RIKEN integrated database of mammals:

http://metadb.riken.jp/metadb/download/SciNetS_ria254i

The files can be downloaded without registration under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.